# Chrome silent printing issue

Tags: google-chrome, printing, silent

I'm having an issue using the --kiosk --kiosk-printing mode in chome.

I'm using chrome 20.x.

The first page prints fine, however all the next pages are coming entirely blank, not even header...

Does anyone know of a fix?

Also does anyone know of a different browser that has a kiosk and silent printing mode?
(Firefox plugins seem to have lots of bugs...)

Thank you

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Have you solved this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you want to check your idle time?

Comment: can you please explain this briefly?